# drawing the Mandelbrot set with libGDX

Tags: android, libgdx

I want to try rendering the mandelbrot set using libGDX on AIDE (I only have my phone to code with). So, I studied up on the algorithm and tried implementing it.

This function is called for every pixel on the screen-

```
public int calcFract(int x, int y, int maxiter)
{
    zx = zy = 0;
    cx = (x - width/2) / zoom;
    cy = (y - height/2) / zoom;

    while( zx * zx + zy * zy < 4.0 && iter < maxiter )
    {
        tmp = zx * zx - zy * zy + cx;
        zy = 2.0 * zx * zy + cy;
        zx = tmp;
        iter++;
    }

    return iter | iter << 8;
}
```

And here is the create() callback-

```
public void create()
{
    width = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    height = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(this);
    fractal = new Pixmap(width, height, Pixmap.Format.RGB888);
    for (int i = 0; i < width; ++i)
        for (int j = 0; j < height; ++j)
        {
            int c = mandelbrot.calcFract(i, j, maxiter);
            fractal.drawPixel( i, j, Color.toIntBits(0xff, c, c, c));
        }

     fracTex = new Texture(fractal);
     batch = new SpriteBatch();
}
```

The app compiles without errors, but when I run it, it shows me this-

[notice the left side of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PEk0e.png)

Here is the render() callback as well-

```
public void render()
{   
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(fracTex, 0, 0);
    batch.end();
}
```

Please tell me if there's anything wrong with my code. 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please help me figure this out, ppl.

Comment: The image is black for me. What do you mean by "notice the left side of the screen"?

Comment: There is a single pixel wide line with a gradient pattern on the left side of the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a very nooby mistake.

If you look at my code, you will notice that after rendering the first pixel of the pixmap, the algorithm stops working because iter gets stuck at maxiter forever because I forgot to reset iter for every pixel. The while loop is skipped since `iter = maxiter` for all pixels after the first one. This means that all pixels after the first one take on the same colour, ruining everything.

I fixed it by setting iter to 0 before the while loop in calcFract().